# How to export JavaFX to an Application on MacOS

Tags: macos, kotlin, javafx

I have a JavaFX application I wrote in Kotlin, All i want to do is to export it as an application so i can click it on my desktop and it will run.

I tried jlink but it gave me:

```
jlink error: Error: Output directory is empty
```

and I tried javapackager:

```
javapackager -deploy -native image -outdir ~/Desktop -outfile AntelopeSystemManager -srcdir /Users/nadavholtzman/Documents/AntelopeSystemManager/out/artifacts/AntelopeSystemManager_jar -srcfiles AntelopeSystemManager.jar -appclass ui.AntelopeSystemManagerUI -B-jvmOptions=-Djava.home=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home -verbose
```

But then my terminal gets stuck on loading...

I've been trying for a few days now and it's so frustrating.

Can anyone help?

Comment: @SedJ601 It has one module and i'm using maven

Comment: Use `Automator.app` to run a shell script, or copy `jlink` output to an application bundle; more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info). What have you tried?

Comment: @trashgod I trie jlink but it gave me: 
jlink error: Error: Output directory is empty

and I tried javapackager:

javapackager -deploy -native image -outdir ~/Desktop -outfile AntelopeSystemManager -srcdir /Users/nadavholtzman/Documents/AntelopeSystemManager/out/artifacts/AntelopeSystemManager_jar -srcfiles AntelopeSystemManager.jar -appclass ui.AntelopeSystemManagerUI -B-jvmOptions=-Djava.home=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home -verbose

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Given your use of `jlink`, it must be Java 9+. But `javapackager` has been deprecated and removed for a while now (I don't remember which version exactly). It was replaced by [`jpackage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jpackage/packaging-overview.html), which was added in Java 16.

Comment: Last I tried, it appeared that jpackage on OS X would also require a paid OS X [Developer ID](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jpackage/support-application-features.html#GUID-8D9F0607-91F4-4070-8823-02FCAB12238D) for [app signing acceptable to gatekeeper](https://developer.apple.com/developer-id/).

Comment: @NadavHoltzman: I use [`javafx-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin) to invoke `jlink`. Use `Automator.app` while you sort out the rest.

Comment: @trashgod can you please explain how to do it with automator? it will be really helpfull